# Making a subrequest in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I try to do the follwoing request in SQLAlchemy (ORM) :

SELECT id, ref_prog FROM stepvand_1c_1t.equipment_day_hour
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM stepvand_1c_1t.equipment WHERE equipment_type='L')

I did :

```
subq = session.query(Equipment)
subq = subq.filter(Equipment.equipment_type == "L").subquery()

query = session.query(EquipmentDayHour)
query = query.filter(EquipmentDayHour.id.in_(subq))
```

But that doesn't work...

Python tells me that the subrequest has too many columns.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should only change one line of your sample code:

```
# error: includes all columns of Equipment
`subq = session.query(Equipment)`
# correct: include only ID column
`subq = session.query(Equipment.id)`
```

However, I believe that you can do this without subquery:

```
query = (session.query(EquipmentDayHour).
         # version-1: if you have a relationship between EquipmentDayHour and Equipment
         join(Equipment).
         # version-2: if you do not have such relationship
         #join(Equipment, EquipmentDayHour.id==Equipment.id).
         filter(Equipment.equipment_type == "L")
        )
```

Comment: Thanks. It does now compile, but the result is false. I sould have one entry as result, and I get none. I should have one entry.</br>  If before the use of the subquery, I apply the all() function, and print them, I get a list of one tuple, with an element (the value I should get).

Comment: I am trying your alternative.